# MySQL - merge tables into one

Tags: mysql

I need to move some data from few tables into one. So far I've got this (doesn't work):

```
SELECT * INTO MainT FROM table1 WHERE MainT.sun=table1.sun
```

`MainT` - this table have a lot of data
I want to add data from `table1` to `MainT` if `sun` value is the same. `sun` column is in every table.
I already create fields/columns from `table1` in `MainT` table.

This query give me this error:

```
#1327 - Undeclared variable: MainT
```

I also tried to run this:

```
SELECT * INTO `MainT` FROM table1 WHERE `MainT`.sun=table1.sun
```

error is the same

**UPDATE**

```
INSERT INTO `MainT` SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE `MainT`.sun=table1.sun;
#1054 - Unknown column 'MainT.sun' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: ***What*** doesn't work?

Comment: do you get an error message? In what way does it not work?

Comment: this query, give me 1 min, i will display sql error.

Comment: Please edit the post and show the SQL error.

Comment: can you explain what where clause you are trying to write?

Comment: The [SELECT ... INTO](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-into.html) syntax is used to store results in a file or variable.

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into MainT
select * from table1
where ...
```

Comment: thx for help, can you have a quick look on updated post please.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly try something like

```
INSERT INTO MainT
SELECT * 
FROM table1 AS t
INNER JOIN MaintT AS mt ON mt.sun = t.sun
```